# Choosing rows based on grouping condition and field condition

Tags: r, select

I would like to know how could I choose out these plots where I have together trees "HB" and "KU"?

This is an example of my dataset:

```
       plot ID             tree
1    10000503711            LV
2  1000057448111            LV
3  1000057448111            HB
4  1000057448111            KU
5    10000603711            LV
6  1000063448111            TM
7  1000063448111            KS
```

So the result should be something like this (it shouldn't erase other tree species from my dataset but it should choose those plot ID-s where there are both "KU" and "HB"):

```
   2  1000057448111            LV
   3  1000057448111            HB
   4  1000057448111            KU
```

Note that some plots have multiple trees growing in them resulting multiple rows per plot. And some plots only have one tree species.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` this could be done. But aggregate could also be used.

Edit: using a new dataset to handle this test case of containing both HB and KU.

```
options(scipen = 50)
library(dplyr)
ss <- read.table(text = "       plot ID             tree
                 1    10000503711            LV
                 2  1000057448111            LV
                 3  1000057448111            HB
                 4  1000057448111            KU
                 5    10000603711            LV
                 5    10000603711            HB
                 6  1000063448111            TM
                 7  1000063448111            KS", header = T)


ss %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(trees = paste0(tree, collapse = "_")) %>%
  filter(grepl('HB_KU|KU_HB',trees)) %>%  distinct(ID) %>% 
  inner_join(.,ss)
```

Output:

```
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [?]
             ID  plot   tree
          <dbl> <int> <fctr>
1 1000057448111     2     LV
2 1000057448111     3     HB
3 1000057448111     4     KU
```

Comment: Is the `group_by` necessary in this case?

Comment: My assumption was the filter is applied after `group_by` but seems without that the same output is displayed. Do you think i should remove it?

Comment: Since I actually have other colums also and this was a simplified example, then I think you shouldn't remove "group_by".

Comment: But there's a slight problem - it gives me these plots also which have only one tree species ("HB") but not both: "HB" and "KU".

Comment: Has it been fixed?

Comment: No, it gives me all the plots which have either HB or KU or both of them, but I need to have a dataset of plots where are both of these tree species not only one of them.

Comment: Please find the updated answer where I've tried to create a new variable and filter it.

Comment: Oh, sorry! But it gives me an error: Error in inner_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) : 
  unknown column ''

Comment: Weird, Can you check what are you getting without `inner_join`

Comment: I think the reason is there should be group_by("plot ID") but I tried to change the plot ID title in read.table to ID and it gave me an error: duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed.
So I left it as it was.

And for your question: 
> ss %>% 
+   group_by(ID) %>% 
+   mutate(trees = paste0(tree, collapse = "_")) %>%
+   filter(grepl('HB_KU|KU_HB',trees)) %>%  distinct(ID)
Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
Groups: ID [1]

             ID            ID
          <dbl>         <dbl>
1 1000057448111 1000057448111

Comment: Actually, what I can do, is merge these given ID-s with my original file and it gives me an output where there's only those plots (with it's other columns) which have both tree species. It's a little bit handywork but it's one way to find a solution. :)

Comment: It is weird yeah, because I copied excactly the same script you wrote here. But thanks anyway, because without you I couldn't have done it!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base solution.

```
ss <- read.table(text = "       plot ID             tree
1    10000503711            LV
                 2  1000057448111            LV
                 3  1000057448111            HB
                 4  1000057448111            KU
                 5    10000603711            LV
                 6  1000063448111            TM
                 7  1000063448111            KS", header = TRUE,
                 colClasses = c("numeric", "character", "character"))

ss[ss$ID %in% unique(ss[ss$tree %in% c("HB", "KU"), "ID"]), ]

  plot            ID tree
2    2 1000057448111   LV
3    3 1000057448111   HB
4    4 1000057448111   KU
```

Comment: Thank you, but it only worked with this simplified version o my dataset but not when I had more colums (I have about 30 colums actually in my dataset).

Comment: It is my bad yes, I thought that it's enough and I shouldn't make this too complicated but it seems I made it too plain.